# How can i insert image url in database using jsp and hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, servlets

I've been trying but it's just not happening please if anyone knows tell me how to do this..

Comment: Part filePart=request.getPart("file");
String fileName = Paths.get(filePart.getSubmittedFileName()).getFilePart filePart=request.getPart("file");
String fileName =Paths.get(filePart.getSubmittedFileName()).getFileName().toString();Name().toString();

Comment: <form action="save" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
<input type="file" name="file">

Answer (score 0):

do mean upload image on your server and save the url in your database ?

Comment: yes sir that is what i want to do.For single or multiple images.